# Tools for modelling and visualizing growth of cells

Tags: cell-biology, theoretical-biology, biopython

I am looking for a program/GUI app/package that would help me do simulations for cell growth. I have a microscopic mathematical model, and the scenario is basically the following: I start with a rod-shaped cell characterized my its center and direction angle, it grows until it reaches a certain length, it divides into two identical cells whose angles change randomly and the process continues.

Is there any program or package that I can use for such a situation? I have found several on GitHub, but they were mostly for very complicated biological processes. I use Python/Julia/Matlab and can code, but I was wondering whether there are any tools for such simpler scenarios.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE]. Thanks! 

Comment: Hello, mathematical modeler here.  Some context about your model would be helpful.  It seems like a PDE model, for which, generally, people write their own code.  There are some packages that would help - such as finite difference (or other) numerical approximations for the gradient and Laplacian, but without details it is hard to know where to direct you